# How to include job from the upstream project to the downstream project in a multi project pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, include, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I use [multi-project pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines) with GitLab. I want to include a job from the upstream project into the downstream project. I can include the job from default branch, but not from the depended commit. It uses `HEAD`.

**Upstream pipeline**

```yaml
.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to $SERVER_HOST"

trigger-downstream:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: dur/downstream-project
  except:
    - pipelines
```

In real life I would separate the jobs in two different files to make it easier for the downstream project to include only one job of the upstream project.

**Downstream pipeline**

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'dur/upstream-project'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'

deploy-test:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    SERVER_HOST: test.mycompany.com
  environment:
    name: test

deploy-prod:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    SERVER_HOST: prod.mycompany.com
  environment:
    name: prod
```

**Research**

- I read [`include:project`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includeproject):

  > - `include:ref`: Optional. The ref to retrieve the file from. Defaults to the `HEAD` of the project when not specified.

  However, I see no way to get the ref from the upstream project. I see no [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) with the ref from the upstream project.
- I read [Use variables with include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include):

  > You cannot use variables defined in jobs, or in a global `variables` section which defines the default variables for all jobs. Includes are evaluated before jobs, so these variables cannot be used with `include`.

  So I cannot copy the ref in the upstream project to a job variable and use this variable in the `include` in the downstream project.

**Question**

Is there any way to include the current pipeline file of the upstream project into the downstream project?